# Plotting function takes forever

Tags: performance-tuning, probability-or-statistics

I have this simple code, but it takes ages to plot the last function: FS12... how to speed it up?
Thank you

```
Clear["Global`*"];

(*Initial Input data*)

u11 = 1;
(*s11=u11*0.05;*)

s11 = u11*1;

d1 = 50; p1 = 0.1;

u22 = 1;
(*s22=u22*0.25;*)

s22 = u22*0.4;

d2 = 50; p2 = 0.1;

t0 = 50;

F = 0.99;

fS11[r_] := PDF[NormalDistribution[u11, s11], r];

Quiet[Plot[fS11[r], {r, 0, 2}, AspectRatio -> 0.2, PlotRange -> Full]]

FS11[r_] := CDF[NormalDistribution[u11, s11], r];
Quiet[Plot[FS11[r], {r, 0, 4}, AspectRatio -> 0.2, PlotRange -> Full]]

FS1[x_] := (1 - p1)*UnitStep[x] + p1*FS11[x];
Quiet[plt1 = 
  Plot[FS1[x], {x, -2, 3}, AspectRatio -> 0.2, PlotRange -> Full, 
   PlotStyle -> Blue]]

Quiet[dataS1 = 
   Table[x /. FindRoot[FS1[x] == y, {x, -1, 5}], {y, 0, 0.99, 0.001}]];

FS1n[x_] := CDF[SmoothKernelDistribution[dataS1], x]

Quiet[plt2 = 
  Plot[FS1n[x], {x, -2, 4}, AspectRatio -> 0.2, PlotRange -> Full, 
   PlotStyle -> Red]]

Show[plt1, plt2]

fS1n[x_] := PDF[SmoothKernelDistribution[dataS1], x];

Quiet[Plot[fS1n[x], {x, -1, 2}, AspectRatio -> 0.2, PlotRange -> Full]]

fS22[x_] := PDF[NormalDistribution[u22, s22], x] 

Quiet[Plot[fS22[x], {x, -3, 3}, AspectRatio -> 0.2, PlotRange -> Full]]

FS22[x_] := CDF[NormalDistribution[u22, s22], x]

Quiet[Plot[FS22[x], {x, 0, 3}, AspectRatio -> 0.2, PlotRange -> Full]]

FS2[x_] := ((1 - p2)*UnitStep[x] + p2*FS22[x])^(d1/d2)

Quiet[Plot[FS2[x], {x, -2, 4}, AspectRatio -> 0.2, PlotRange -> Full]]

FS12[x_] := Evaluate[NIntegrate[fS1n[y]*FS2[x - y], {y, -4, +4}]];

Quiet[Plot[FS12[x], {x, 0, 2}, AspectRatio -> 0.2, PlotRange -> Full]]
```

Comment: Have you considered possibly rephrasing your problem using tools such as `(N)Probability`, `(N)Expectation`, `Distributed` and `Conditioned`?

Comment: The definition of FS12 throws the following message in v12 on Mac: NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand (\[Piecewise] <<1>>) (0.05 Erfc[1.76777 (1-x+y)]+0.9 UnitStep[x-y]) has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{-4,-3.99987}}.  I'm not saying this is the problem but perhaps someone who understands this better might.

Comment: @kirma I don't see how those functions help me in getting FS12 (which is a convolution, although Convolute didn't work for me because fS1n is not a distribution per se)....

Comment: @MarkR yep I get the same warning but I don't know if that's the cause

Comment: The more I think about this is that the distrbiution from which `dataS1` was sampled is just not smooth. So using `SmoothKernelDistribution` does not make any sense. The same holds for the convolution against its PDF: It just does not exist.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher at the beginning I didn't use SmoothKernelDistribution. But I got errors in determining FS12 if I determined fS1 by fS1[x_]:=(1-p1)*DiracDelta[x]+p1*fS11[x], or fS1[x_]:=D[FS1[x],x]...

Comment: Just because something else did not work, it does not mean that this thing is right. For example, it is certainly wrong to slap your neighbour on their right cheek. That does not mean that slapping them on their left cheek were any better. ;)

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Right :) but these equations, i.e. FS1, fS1, FS2, FS12 are given in a paper of the 80s and solved I don't know how if in 2020 they cannot be...

Comment: Hmm. You actually want to calculate the distribution of  random variable `X+Y`, right? You can do that by convolving their PDFs, if existent. Here, one one of the two random variables has a density, so you may apply [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/264119) to determine the CDF of `X+Y` instead.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher yes I tried Convolve function but I couldn't get it to work... I also think that the inputs for the Convolve function in mathematica is a pdf, this case fS1 and a CDF in this case FS2... Since it integrates one time according to the documentation.

Comment: The point is that you have to convolve a CDF against a PDF here (Lebesgue-Stieltjes convolution of a CDF against a CDF) in order to obtain the CDF of $X+Y$. But you seemed to have tried convoluting two PDFs one of which does not exist.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I did use a PDF and a CDF but fS1 or fS2 they are formulated the same... I think they exist but they are not smooth so numerically they are challenging

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of the cases where `Set` should be preferred over `SetDelayed` in a function definition:

```
FS1n[x_] := CDF[SmoothKernelDistribution[dataS1], x];

Quiet[plt2 = 
     Plot[FS1n[x], {x, -2, 4}, AspectRatio -> 0.2, PlotRange -> Full, 
      PlotStyle -> Red]]; // AbsoluteTiming // First

Block[{x},
  FS1n[x_] = CDF[SmoothKernelDistribution[dataS1], x];
  ];

Quiet[plt2 = 
     Plot[FS1n[x], {x, -2, 4}, AspectRatio -> 0.2, PlotRange -> Full, 
      PlotStyle -> Red]]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 7.21294
>
> 0.047187

So a more than 100-fold speed up. Why? `SmoothKernelDistribution[dataS1]` has to build an interpolation function first by doing some statistical tricks. If you use `SetDelayed`, this computation has to be performed _every time you call `FS1n`. With `Set`, this has to be done only once, precisely at the time of definition of `FS1n`.

This does not completely resolve the slowness of the last plot, though. That is due to some problem in `NIntegrate`. Have to think about it...

Comment: Actually if I use`Block[{x},FS12[x_]=NIntegrate[fS1n[y]*FS2[x-y],{y,-4,+4}];];` it takes 3sec longer that if I use `FS12[x_]:=NIntegrate[fS1n[y]*FS2[x-y],{y,-4,+4}];`...

Comment: Apparently... when I use `fS1[x_]:=(1-p1)*DiracDelta[x]+p1*fS11` it works super fast...

Comment: `NIntegrate` is a case where you do not want to use `Set` (or `SetDelayed`+`Evaluate`)...

Comment: And towards the second comment: Yes, _now_ you are convolutin the correct CDF against the correct PDF... =) Convolution against a `DiracDelta` is pretty easy in the end ;)

Comment: But if I define `fS1[x_] := D[FS1[x], x]` it works as well, but I get an error when I ask to Plot fS1: `General::ivar: -1.83665 is not a valid variable. General::stop: Further output of General::ivar will be suppressed during this calculation.`... strange

Comment: Yeah, because when `x` is substituted by a numerical value, it cannot be used as symbol in `D` anymore. But wait, I am confused: You are trying again to take the PDF of the empirical distribution, right? But `FS2 ` might have the simpler "PDF" (containing a `DiracDelta`), so what about `NIntegrate[FS1n[y]*fS2[x - y], {y, -4, +4}]`?

Comment: No, If I define `FS1[x_] = (1 - p1)*UnitStep[x] + p1*FS11[x];` and `fS1[x_] := D[FS1[x], x];` the program works... but I get the above error when `Plot[fS1[x], {x, -2, 2}, AspectRatio -> 0.2, PlotRange -> Full]`. If I use the Dirac everything works.... but it should be the same, no?

Comment: Sorry, I am quite confused and actually also busy, you know... But if it works for you, it is fine for me. =)

Comment: Actually it doesn't work for p1!=1.... Nintegrate cannot handle the discrete part!

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps not very satisfying, but I was able to get this to complete in a reasonable amount of time (1 minute, 16 seconds):

```
plotValues = ParallelTable[{x, FS12[x]}, {x, 0.01, 2, .01}];
ListPlot[plotValues, AspectRatio -> 0.2, PlotRange -> Full]
```

My machine is a Mac running v12 and it has 6 kernels.

Here is the plot: 
[image: ListPlot of FS12]

UPDATE:
I went back and started at 0 and notice that there is a discontinuity between 0 and .01: 
[image: ListPlot of FS12 starting at 0]
This doesn't explain the problem since even starting Plot at .01 takes a long time.

Comment: That's good. I'll try in my machine. Thank you!

Comment: I did notice that the interpolating function used by FS12 has some discontinuities with very small numbers.  Here are the first few values with a step size of .001: {0., 130.44}, {0.001, 110.191}, {0.002, 89.9411}, {0.003, 69.6915}, \
{0.004, 49.442}, {0.005, 29.1925}, {0.006, 8.94294}, {0.007, \
5.28131}, {0.008, 4.32973}, {0.009, 3.37815}, {0.01, 2.42657}, \
{0.011, 1.47499}, {0.012, 0.523408}, {0.013, 1.88788*10^-17}, {0.014, 
 1.5711*10^-17}, {0.015, 1.25433*10^-17}, {0.016, 
 9.3755*10^-18}, {0.017, 6.20772*10^-18}, {0.018, 
 3.03995*10^-18}, {0.019, 0.}, {0.02, 0.}, {0.021, 0.}

Comment: I think you are referring to `dataS1`, well yes, FS1 is a mixture distribution....

Comment: Yes, I mean that fS1n evaluates to an interpolating function and that is what has the discontinuities.

Comment: I had to do it because the way FS1 is built.... I couldn't get mathematica to work when determining FS12 if I determined fS1n by the derivative of FS1 or if I defined fS1[x_]:=(1-p1)*DiracDelta[x]+p1*fS11. But it works with SmoothKernelDistribution or EmpiricalDistribution... Just awful slowly